# Inverse function, bijection

Tags: functions

Can you help me find the inverse function for f such that :
[image: J is yet to be determined but I found that it equals R and I have also proven that it's a continuous and strictly monotonous function so no problem with that]

J is yet to be determined but I found that it equals R and I have also proven that it's a continuous and strictly monotonous function so no problem with that

Comment: Reciprocal function $g(x)=1/f(x)$ or inverse function $f^{-1}(f(x))=x?$

Comment: @gammatester inverse it is then. Sorry for that.

Comment: Where you get problems? Just solve $f(x)=y$.

Comment: @gammatester yeah well I used delta to solve the equation and it got really complicated with multiple options and results and it wasn't a way to eliminate one of them so I figured there may exist another way of doing it

Comment: What is delta? $f(x)=y$ results in a quadratic equation.

Comment: @gammatester sorry again. It's the quadratic formula. The problem is you also need a quadratic formula for the former quadratic forumla to know when it's positive and when otherwise. So I ended up getting a lot of cases and too many solutions which I can't eliminate. Yet I only need one inverse function.

Answer (score 1):

Solving $f(x)=y$ gives
$$g(y)= \frac{-2+3y \pm \sqrt{4+y^2}}{2y}$$
Using the $+$ solution you get 
$$f(g(x)) = \frac{1}{2-g(x)}
+ \frac{1}{1-g(x)}$$
$$=\frac{1}{2-\frac{-2+3x+\sqrt{4+x^2}}{2x}}
+ \frac{1}{1-\frac{-2+3x+\sqrt{4+x^2}}{2x}}$$
$$=\frac{4x(-2+\sqrt{4+x^2})}{(x+2-\sqrt{4+x^2})(x-2+\sqrt{4+x^2})}$$
$$=\frac{4x(-2+\sqrt{4+x^2})}{-8+4\sqrt{4+x^2}} = x$$

Comment: @math-lover: Thank you, corrected.

Comment: How is this eliminating one answer ? Both values of y verify f(g(x)) = x because they're both answers of the equation. Can you please give further explanation ?

Comment: @Abbkey: One difference between 
$$g(y)= \frac{-2+3y + \sqrt{4+y^2}}{2y}$$
and 
$$h(y)= \frac{-2+3y - \sqrt{4+y^2}}{2y}$$
is that, $g(y)$ has a removable singularity at zero with $\lim_{y\rightarrow 0}g(y)=3/2$, whereas the singularity of $h(y)$ is **not** removable.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't understand this concept for we haven't studied this (i'm in high school) so if you can please think of another way of eliminating one answer i'd be really grateful.

Comment: @Abbkey: In other words: $g(x)$ can be continuously extended to a function with the domain $\mathbb{R},$ whereas $g(x)$ cannot.

Comment: I'm more familiar with the way you're putting it now. I think I understand. Thank you so much.